# Can't return result from a call to an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my code:

```
export async function fetchData(searchValue) {
    await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchValue}&app_id=${apiId}&app_key=${apiKey}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                return result;
            },
            (error) => {
                return (`Error: ${error}`);
            }
        )
}
```

The issue is:

I can't return the result to other component, but if I logged that value into the console, I can see the value, any help?

If I return the statement "await fetch" I can console log the object but I don't know how to access the data [you can see on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgBZQ.png)

Comment: How do you call this code in the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your function like this:

```js
export async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchValue}&app_id=${apiId}&app_key=${apiKey}`
        );
        return await response.json();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    }
}
```